# How to make a letter go to the next character?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question about Macro VBA. Suppose I have a letter, like "C". I want to know the command that, when executed, adds an advance to it and makes it "D". For example, in Java, you only need to write "character ++", where character = "C". Now, "character" becomes "D". I was wondering how to do this in VBA.

Comment: Probably something along the lines of `Chr(Asc("C")+1)`

Comment: @JvdV perfectly working, thank you